# FlexLayout bindable source -xamarin forms - how to get data without binding

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I would like to use the flex layout binding itemsource without the real binding. I would like to generate the list data from behind the page c# . I had to do it since this page is loading 6 more different lists with different data sources and for a reason, I don't know the binding is not getting into the view, so I decided to move all the list results to the page behind and display all the other lists.

This is what I have

**xaml**

```
                        <FlexLayout x:name="painfullist" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
                              <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                  <DataTemplate>
                                     <Button Padding="20" CornerRadius="25" Text="{Binding Value}" />
                                     </DataTemplate>
                              </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </FlexLayout>
```

**c#**  I tried to bind with the view model but the data just dont show up. so my plan b is to get it from behind the page.

```
BindingContext = vm;

var getamenities = vm.Amenities;

painfullist.ItemsSource = new List<Amenitys>(getamenities);
```

Comment: `FlexLayout` doesn't have `ItemsSource`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60042290/how-can-i-bind-an-observable-collection-to-a-flexlayout-in-xamarin

Answer (score 1):

`ItemsSource` is an attached property in the `BindableLayout` class, to set it in code for the `BindableObject` (FlexLayout):

```
BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(painfullist, vm.Amenities); //Amenities better to be ObservableCollection
```

Comment: I don't have that property SetItemsSource in the BindableLayout

Comment: what Forms version do you have?